# Cluster Validation on Hamming Distances/K-Modes

Tags: r, machine-learning, clustering, validation

I wondered if anyone could recommend internal cluster validation resources in R capable of estimating $k^*$ prior to using k-modes?

Therefore, I wondered if anyone knew of existing internal validation libraries in R capable of working with Hamming distances?

And failing these standard internal validation approaches, I've noticed some research uses the value of the minimised objective function per $k$, would this be a valid approach?

Would appreciate any assistance with this.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.